# Bring to front single selection in multi-line chart

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I am plotting a multi-line chart using a single selector to make a line stand out.
The problem is that when I select one line and the others get recolored, the selected line is buried under some other lines, while I would like it come to the front, to be fully visible. I could use `alt.value('transparent')`, but this would simply make all the other lines disappear, instead I would like them to be still visible and in the background.
Is there a way to make this work?

In my example below I have 10 lines and it seems that vega-lite is plotting first line A, then on top of it line B, till line L. Therefore only the last column in the DataFrame, line L, is fully visible if selected.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's the code to reproduce the chart:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

#Dataframe creation
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,10)+10, 
                  index=np.arange(2001,2016),
                  columns=list('ABCDEFGHIL'))
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.melt(id_vars='index')

#chart creation
selection = alt.selection(type='single', fields=['variable'])
color = alt.condition(selection,
                  alt.Color('variable:N', legend=None),
                  alt.value('lightblue'))

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    y = 'value',
    x = 'index:O',
    color = color,
    tooltip = 'variable:N'
).add_selection(
    selection
).properties(
    width=400
)

legend = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='variable:N',
    color=color
).add_selection(
    selection
).properties(
    width=400
)

line & legend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a selection to change the z-order of the lines, but you can use a layering trick to get the same effect by creating another layer of lines that is filtered on the selection from the first.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

#Dataframe creation
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,10)+10, 
                  index=np.arange(2001,2016),
                  columns=list('ABCDEFGHIL'))
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.melt(id_vars='index')

#chart creation
selection = alt.selection(type='single', fields=['variable'])
color = alt.condition(selection,
                  alt.Color('variable:N', legend=None),
                  alt.value('lightblue'))

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    y = 'value',
    x = 'index:O',
    color = alt.value('lightblue'),
    detail = 'variable:N',
    tooltip = 'variable:N'
).add_selection(
    selection
).properties(
    width=400
)

# layer that accomplishes the highlighting
line_highlight = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    y = 'value',
    x = 'index:O',
    color = 'variable:N',
).transform_filter(
    selection
).properties(
    width=400
)

legend = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='variable:N',
    color=color
).add_selection(
    selection
).properties(
    width=400
)

(line + line_highlight) & legend
```

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp for your help (and your work on Altair), it is a very effective solution!